# RSpec, Factory Girl and Capybara: no items saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot, database-cleaner

I have mountable Rails engine with RSpec:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy= example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Simple factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post, :class => MyEngine::Post do
    title 'title'
  end
end
```

Capybara feature:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Post', :type => :feature do
  let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create :post }

  it 'index action should have post' do
    visit posts_path
    expect(page).to have_text(post.title)
  end
end
```

And Post model doesn't have any validations.

But when i running tests it shows that there is no posts created.

Also ActiveRecord logs:

```
INSERT INTO "my_engine_posts" ...
RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
rollback transaction
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This spec will always fail.

`let` in RSpec is lazy loading. `post` is not actually created until you reference it in:

```
expect(page).to have_text(post.title)
```

So you can either use `let!` which is not lazy loading or reference `post` before you visit the page:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Post', :type => :feature do
  let(:post) { FactoryGirl.create :post }

  it 'index action should have post' do
    post
    visit posts_path
    expect(page).to have_text(post.title)
  end
end
```